# Multiple Points attribute information into one Point in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, point, attribute-table, expression

I have three points from two layers ( Point 2539 and 2538 from one layer lets say X and point AL101974 from layer Y ) ( Refer figure-1 below).

Point 2539 and 2538 has multiple attribute information ( figure-2) i wanted to add those information into point AL10974 along with distance of each point from AL10974 ( this distance we need to create not already in attribute)

I have used the Distance to nearest hub (Points) tool to get distance and other information but this will populate two columns ( when i am putting source layer as as layer X ) - fig 3 for reference.

I wanted to all these in one row so i will calculate further statistical analysis on it.
[image: Figure1]
[image: Figure2]
[image: Figure 3]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Join attributes by nearest`. It will create a new layer `joined layer` - a copy of `Y`, but if you set `Maximum nearest neighbors` to 2, you will get two duplicate features with the attributes from both points from `X`. You also get an attribute for the distance. You can now copy the attributes from line 2 to line 1.

To add the attribute values of feature no. 2 to feature no. 1, use `Refactor fields` ([see documentation Refactor fields](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectortable.html#refactor-fields)). Create new fields with the same name, but a prefix (like `2_`) and this expression: `attribute (get_feature_by_id (@layer,2), '[attribute_name]')`, where you have to replace `[attribute_name]` with the name of the attribute to be copied (screenshot 2).

If you have a lot of attributes to copy, you can run `Refactor fields` in batch mode.

The result looks like this: Values form line 2 are copied at the end of line 1. You can now delete the second feature:
[image]

*Screenshot 2, `Refactor fields` dialog window: the joined attributes coming from layer `X` in the `joined layer` are copied so that the values of the 2nd feature will be copied as new attributes with the prefix `2_` to the first feature:*
[image]

Comment: Thanks Babel for suggestion. I will try this one but i am afraid as i have multiple points and due to nearest function this will calculate wrong distance from other nearest point. I Have tried oher option like Distance to nearest hub (points) and result are really messed up.  Any suggestion to overcome such issue.. For each point of Y i have two points of X layers.

Comment: It's difficult to say without seeing your data because the solution must be adapted to what you have. Can you provide your data (or a sample of it) for testing?

Comment: @ Babel yes i can provide you .. Let me know the how to provide

Comment: You can upload your data to some cloud service like wetransfer

Comment: Hi Babel Please follow the below link to get sample data.  I have also placed one pdf for better understanding of query.                     https://we.tl/t-oacey6PVD5

Answer (score 0):

Finally there is solution:

Using MMQGIS plugin we can create the hub distance as there is dropdown from where we can specify common field.

MMQGIS Plugin > Create > Hub distance